# 2G or 3G network standards

Tags: mobile, standardisation

Can you list me names of the standards from where I can prove that 2G phones will not work over 3G network?

I know it's a common fact but I need something like a standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is way too wide. There's protocol stack for 2G, and for 3G. They're different. Frequencies are different. Even controller/core is at least logically different. For documentation you can visit http://www.3gpp.org/specifications. Find protocol stacks and compare them "line by line" if it meets your purpose.

Comment: artem_d93 I don't think it is a wide question. I need a statement that is equivalent to something like "if a phone supports only 2G it can not work over 3G".

Comment: @dvvcnxc It can't because protocol stacks of 3G and 2G aren't interoperable at least. As if you're trying to plug 6.3mm jack into 3.5. If you need details, you'll find them in 3GPP documentation.